# Inconsistent function call in C# - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm running these functions on an update loop. The first Debug.Log() prints 2 values, the second Debug.Log() prints two different values. How is this possible if one function is calling the other?

```
private void Blend(Pose pose) {
    Debug.Log(pose.name);
    // reset previous animation
    unBlend(previousPose);
    // queue new pose
    BlendQ.Enqueue(pose);
}


private void unBlend(Pose pose) {
    Debug.Log(pose.name);
    // only unblend if new pose is different
    //if (pose.name == previousPose.name) return;
    if (!running2) {
        running2 = true;
        StartCoroutine(IRun2(pose.name, pose.curve, pose.blendSpeed));
    }
}
    
    
public class Pose {
    public string name;
    public float blendSpeed;
    public AnimationCurve curve;

    public Pose(string name, AnimationCurve curve, float blendSpeed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.curve = curve;
        this.blendSpeed = blendSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the output you're seeing.

Comment: Where is `previousPose` coming from? And why is your `class Pose` using mutable fields?

Comment: Well one debug prints pose  where as the post going to unblend is previouspose. Easily 2 different values

Comment: @BugFinder, that's a good observation. Thank you.